# WSO2 : how to preserve Content-Type in http header with mediation

Tags: wso2, content-type

I'm using wso2am with 1.10.0 version.

I have a API (Content-Type: multipart/form-data)
but when request invoked, endpoint(real api server) can't receive Content-Type header.

I found a solution.
http://prabu-lk.blogspot.kr/2015/09/how-to-preserving-http-headers-in-wso2.html
but this solution is a global setting.

The reason I can not use this solution is because of the other api.
This api changes the content-type in customhandler.

So i want use mediation to be applied in units of api.

If you know how to fix it, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a custom sequence to API and set the header from there?

Refer document [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) for more info. This should add as an in-sequence.

Your sequence should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="header-sequence">
  <header name="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data"/>
</sequence>
```